# Lost draft under all posts and drafts

Tags: posts, wp-query, wp-admin, editor, draft

I'm trying to delete drafts that I've never created.  I suppose they are auto drafts.  Searched and searched but maybe because it's a super easy fix that no one asks, but can't figure out how to delete them.

Under posts menu, there are (2) drafts, yet when I go to click all posts/drafts, there are no posts found to delete.  I only have one user(admin), I have tried deactivating all plugins. If not, is there a way to manually delete them inside the database?

[image: Under drafts in posts page, there are no posts found, but can be seen having 2 posts]